# Matching keywords with sentence database, how to avoid duplicated keywords in results?

Tags: ruby, database

I'm very new to programming and am a beginner in Ruby. I've done a lot of searching to try to find the answers I need, but nothing seems to match what I'm looking for.

I need to make a program for work that will:

1. Get keywords from the user
2. Match those keywords with the same keywords in a database of sentences, and then
3. Spit out randomized sentences that:

   1. contain all the keywords 1 time
   2. do NOT contain keywords not listed
   3. do NOT duplicate keywords

Important to know: Sentences all have a mix of several keywords, NOT one per sentence

1 & 2 are OK, I've been able to do those. My problem is with part 3. I've tried long lists of "if include?" parameters, but it never ends up working and I know there must be a better way to do this.

My grasp of Ruby (and programming generally) is basic and I don't really know what it can and can't do, so any tips or hints in what functions would be useful would be very very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, my code is an over-long mess of confused "if include?" functions, to be perfectly honest, and I don't think my approach is a very good one. I'm hoping someone with experience can just tell me how they would approach the problem, which functions would be useful.

Comment: Fair enough. Try to describe the problem betten then. I am still not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Best way should be using regular expessios. But I dont know enough about it to solve this problem.

Comment: Basically what I'm struggling with is this: My database has sentences that all have several keywords. I can match user-input keywords and pull matching sentences easily enough, but my results end up being sentences with duplicated keywords. I need to be able to pull out a set of random sentences that represents each user-input keyword just 1 time, without duplication.

Comment: For example: The user inputs A and C. My program matches A with a sentence that has A, B and C. My program then matches C with a sentence that has C but also A. I need a single sentence that has only A and C in it.

Comment: Can you put the code on github?

Comment: Here's a part of the code. Full thing is 2000+ lines! 
if user_keywords.include? 'keyword1'
 keyword1_text=database.grep(/keyword1/)
 keyword1_text2=keyword1_text[(rand((keyword1_text.length))]
 
 until
 ((keyword1_text2 !=~ /keyword2/i or keyword2==0) && (keyword1_text2 !=~ /keyword3/i or keyword3==0) && (keyword1_text2 !=~ /keyword4/i or keyword4==0)  && (keyword1_text2 !=~ /keyword5/i or keyword5==0)  && (keyword1_text2 !=~ /keyword6/i or keyword6==0))
 keyword1_text2 == ''
 keyword1_text2=keyword1_text[(rand((keyword1_text.length))]
 end

Comment: What I've been trying to do is this:
1.) Select a randomized sentence from the database that matches one of the user-input keywords
2.) Add the sentence to an array
3.) Check the array for all possible keywords. If a keyword is found, delete it from the list of user-input keywords and assign that keyword a 1 (instead of a 0)
4.) Repeat for the next keyword in the user-input list, but only accept sentences where all the keywords have a counter value of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the match is found, why don't you consecutively pop it out of your array/db? It will ensure no duplication, since that record would not be present to be matched later. No?
Consider this snippet:

```
db=%q(It is hot today), %q(It is going to rain), %q(Where are you, sonny?), %q(sentence contains is and are)
keyw=%w(is am are)
de=[]
keyw.each do |word|
    for index in 0...db.length  
        if db[index].include?(word)    
            puts "Matched #{word} with #{db[index]}"      
            de<<index
        end  
    end  
    until de.empty?
        db.delete_at(de.pop)
    end
end
```

db is database example and keyw contains keywords.

Corresponding output:

```
Matched is with It is hot today
Matched is with It is going to rain
Matched is with sentence contains is and are
Matched are with Where are you, sonny?
```

No duplication. :)

Comment: Seems like a good step in the right direction! A few questions:
1.) It's OK to use user-input keywords with this code, right?
2.) Is there a way to modify this to output only 1 sentence per keyword? The output gives 2 sentences with "it", but I need the output to have each keyword appear only once.
3.) Could you clarify the function of the "de<<index" line?
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, program can be easily modified to show one result at a time. Just add `break` after the line `de<<index`; and it shall do the required job. :)
And, yes, it will be okay with user-input keywords as well. Just make sure that input strings are `chomp`-ed (`str=gets.chomp`), as unchomped text may create some issue sometime.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This seems to be what I need. :-) I'll use your example as a base and let you know if it works!